# Key error after updating Spider and Anaconda

Tags: python, spyder

After updating to Spyder 4.0.0 (from Spyer 3.7) I get following error on scripts that worked fine before:

*File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1395, in getinfo
    'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"*

With python 3.7.4 I did not get this error. Now with 3.7.1 I have this issue.

Any suggestion? where can I find the root of the issue?

Thank you.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved: the excel file was corrupted